# How to create variables names with iteration and interpolation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, interpolation, fixtures

Suppose there is an association (`bibliography`) between `writers` and `books` and one of the writers, John Pencil, wrote 16 books.
Fixture `bibliography.yml` lists all the books as follows:

```
association_1:
    writer: john_pencil
    book: book_1

association_2:
    writer: john_pencil
    book: book_2

...
```

I need to test that the home page shows the whole list of J.P.'s books. 
Thus if I could use somehow interpolation in the setup method of the test, I could do as follows:

```
(1..16).each do |num|
    book_#{num} = bibliography("association_#{num}".to_sym).book
end
```

then I could test that the books list is present as follows:

```
(1..16).each do |num|
    assert_select "td.book_isdn", book_#{num}.isdn
    assert_select "td.book_title", book_#{num}.title
    assert_select "td.book_genre", book_#{num}.genre
    assert_select "td.book_author", book_#{num}.author  
end
```

Of course, I cannot use `book_#{num}` and I am wondering if I can manage with some expedient to make interpolation work as I did for `"association_#{num}".to_sym`

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, don't do that. Instead, create an array of books and use its elements.

```
books = (1..16).map do |num|
  bibliography("association_#{num}".to_sym).book
end
```

Then

```
books.each do |book|
  assert_select "td.book_isdn", book.isdn
  assert_select "td.book_title", book.title
end
```